# Does the sum of random variables sampled with/without substitution differ for large populations?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

We have a population of $N$ different balls. Half the balls are red, and half the balls are blue. We perform $N$ trials.

In trials $i = 1,\cdots,N$ we pick a ball $B_i$ randomly. First, we pick the balls *with* replacement.  Then we pick the balls *without* replacement.

Define the sum $S = \displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^N \sigma_i$ where for each trial $i \in (2,3,...N)$

$$\sigma_i = \ \begin{cases} 
      1 & \text{if } B_i\text{ has same color as } B_{i-1} \\
      0 & \text{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}
$$
If the balls are picked with replacement the probability mass function (pmf) for $\sigma_i$ is $g(\sigma_i) =  \begin{cases} 
      0.5 & \text{for } \sigma_i=1 \\
      0.5 & \text{for } \sigma_i=0 
   \end{cases} $. Accordingly, the probability mass function for $S$ is described by the Binomial distribution

$$
f(s)= \binom{N-1}{s}\times0.5^{s}\times0.5^{N-1-s}
$$

In the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$, the binomial distribution becomes a Gaussian distribution.

I have performed a few computer simulations where the balls are picked *without* replacement, and the pmf for $S$ converges to the same binomial/Gaussian distribution in the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$. This convergence occurs even if $\sigma_i$ is no longer perfectly i.i.d (independent and identically distributed).

**Why does the sum $S$ converge to the same distribution whether the balls are picked with or without replacement?**

I suspect that I need a central limit theorem for weakly correlated variables.

Note: I want proof, but all explanations are welcome. I suspect there exists a fundamental explanation obvious for somebody with more statistics experience than myself.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb E_{\text{without}}[S] = \mathbb E_{\text{with}}[S] +\frac12$ so you can only say they converge if you rescale

Comment: @Henry - I took your suggestion into account and slightly modified the question.

Comment: That modification (the average not the sum of numbers of changes) does not quite worth with the binomial distribution, plus you would then get convergence to $\frac12$ in a law of large numbers sense. I suspect you want to subtract $\frac{N-1}{2}$ or  $\frac{N}{2}$ and divide by something like $\sqrt{N-1}$ or $\sqrt{N}$.

Comment: Back with the sum, $\mathbb E_{\text{with}}[S] =\frac{N-1}{2}$ while $\mathbb E_{\text{without}}[S]=\frac{N}{2}$, and  $\text{Var}_{\text{with}}[S] =\frac{N-1}{4}$ while $\text{Var}_{\text{without}}[S] =\frac{N(N-2)}{4(N-1)}$.  With suitable relocation and rescaling, each converges to a normal distribution: *with* is the usual CLT and *without* is known but rarely proved.  Since the means and variances are close, applying the relocation and rescaling for one also works for the other as $N$ increases, and that is really what you were asking for originally

Comment: How did you calculate the variance without replacement?
I see your point about the expected values being shifted. I will check what this means for my question tomorrow.

Comment: @LodinEllingsen I looked at every case for $N=2,4,6,8,10$ and the pattern was obvious.  d.k.o. has taken a different approach to come to the same variance, though used $n=\frac N2$

Comment: After reading d.k.o.'s answer, it seems I read your original question too fast: I thought you were using $S$ to count changes rather than non-changes in the sequence. It does not affect the variance, but it does affect the mean, and I should have said $\mathbb E_{\text{with}}[S] =\mathbb E_{\text{without}}[S] =\frac{N-1}{2}$

Comment: I changed the question back to its original version as it fits better with @d.k.o 's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a random binary sequence $s_n$ of size $2n$ s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}s_{n,i}=n$. Then the number of runs of length $2$ ($11$ or $00$) is
$$
S_{2n}=\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}\xi_{n,i}+\zeta_{n,i},
$$
where $\xi_{n,i}=s_{n,i}s_{n,i+1}$ and $\zeta_{n,i}=(1-s_{n,i})(1-s_{n,i+1})$. Now
$$
\mathsf{E}\xi_{n,i}=\mathsf{P}(\xi_{n,i}=1)=\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-2)!n!}\left(\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{n-1}{2n-1},
$$
$$
\mathsf{E}\xi_{n,i}^2=\mathsf{P}(\xi_{n,i}=1),
$$
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}\xi_{n,i}\xi_{n,j}&=\mathsf{P}(\xi_{n,i}=1,\xi_{n,j}=1)=\frac{(2n-4)!}{(n-4)!n!}\left(\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}\right)^{-1} \\
&=\frac{1}{4}\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{(2n-1)(2n-3)},
\end{align}
if $|i-j|>1$, and
$$
\mathsf{E}\xi_{n,i}\xi_{n,j}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{n-2}{2n-1},
$$
if $|i-j|=1$. Finally, $\mathsf{E}\xi_{n,i}\zeta_{n,j}=0$, if $|i-j|\le 1$, and
$$
\mathsf{E}\xi_{n,i}\zeta_{n,j}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{n(n-1)}{(2n-1)(2n-3)},
$$
if $|i-j|>1$.

---

We can compute the moments of $S_{2n}$:
$$
\mathsf{E}S_{2n}=n-1.
$$
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}S_n^2&=\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}\mathsf{E}[\xi_{n,i}^2+\zeta_{n,i}^2]+\sum_{|i-j|=1}\mathsf{E}[\xi_{n,i}\xi_{n,j}+\zeta_{n,i}\zeta_{n,j}] \\
&\quad+\sum_{|i-j|>1}\mathsf{E}[(\xi_{n,i}+\zeta_{n,i})(\xi_{n,j}+\zeta_{n,j})] \\
&=(n-1)+\frac{2(n-1)(n-2)}{2n-1}+\frac{2(n^2-3n+3)(n-1)}{2n-1} \\
&=\frac{(n-1)(2n^2-2n+1)}{2n-1},
\end{align}
and, thus,
$$
\operatorname{Var}(S_{2n})=\frac{n(n-1)}{2n-1}.
$$
As $n\to \infty$, $\mathsf{E}S_{2n}/(2n)\to 1/2$ and $\operatorname{Var}(S_{2n}/\sqrt{2n})\to 1/4$. Also, since $\operatorname{Cov}(\xi_{n,i},\xi_{n,i+1})\to 1/16$, and $\operatorname{Cov}(\xi_{n,i},\xi_{n,j})$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(\xi_{n,i},\zeta_{n,j})$ converge to $0$ when $|i-j|>1$, $(S_{2n}-\mathsf{E}S_{2n})/\sqrt{2n}$ behaves similarly to the same quantity when $s_{n,i}$'s are i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables.

Comment: Excellent work! 
There is an error somewhere in the final part of your work. $(n-1)+\frac{2(n-1)(n-2)}{2 n-1}+\frac{2\left(n^{2}+3 n+3\right)(n-1)}{2 n-1}\neq\frac{(n-1)\left(2 n^{2}-2 n+1\right)}{2 n-1}$, but $\frac{(n-1)\left(2 n^{2}+10n+1\right)}{2 n-1}$.

I have worked through your derivation, but I am unsure exactly where the error is.

Comment: One possible error is your $\sum_{|i-j|=1}\mathsf{E}[\xi_{n,i}\xi_{n,j}+\zeta_{n,i}\zeta_{n,j}]$ value

If I'm not mistaken, there are $2(n-1)$ pairs $(i,j)$ s.t. $|i-j|=1$. In this case we get $2(n-1)\times 2 \times \frac{1}{4}\frac{n-2}{2n-1} = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2n-1}$. This is half of your answer.

Comment: @LodinEllingsen Fixed $(n^2-3n+3)$. BTW, there are $4(n-1)$ pairs with $|i-j|=1$ (we have $2n-1$ elements in total)

Answer (score 0):

The hypergeometric distribution is a discrete probability distribution that describes the probability of k successes in n draws, without replacement, from a finite population of size N that contains exactly K objects with that feature.

If n is large, N and K are large compared to n and p. And p is not close to 0 or 1, then the distribution is closer to normal distribution.